# I want to show always 4 category boxes everytime in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

i am having problem in my website.i am using a shortcode to show a section which is show 4 rand category each time.i mean its changes each time reloads.
now the problem is sometime its showing all 4 rand.sometime it 3 or 2.here my code:

```
function rand_product_categories( $atts ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'number'     => null,
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'columns'    => '4',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'parent'     => '',
        'ids'        => ''
    ), $atts );

    if ( isset( $atts['ids'] ) ) {
        $ids = explode( ',', $atts['ids'] );
        $ids = array_map( 'trim', $ids );
    } else {
        $ids = array();
    }

    $hide_empty = ( $atts['hide_empty'] == true || $atts['hide_empty'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;

    // get terms and workaround WP bug with parents/pad counts
    $args = array(
        'orderby'    => $atts['orderby'],
        'order'      => $atts['order'],
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        'include'    => $ids,
        'pad_counts' => true,
        'child_of'   => $atts['parent']
    );

    $rand_product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    shuffle( $rand_product_categories );
    $rand_product_categories = array_slice( $rand_product_categories, 0, 10 );


    if ( '' !== $atts['parent'] ) {
        $rand_product_categories = wp_list_filter( $rand_product_categories, array( 'parent' => $atts['parent'] ) );
    }

    if ( $hide_empty ) {
        foreach ( $rand_product_categories as $key => $category ) {
            if ( $category->count == 0 ) {
                unset( $rand_product_categories[ $key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $atts['number'] ) {
        $rand_product_categories = array_slice( $rand_product_categories, 0, $atts['number'] );
    }

    $columns = absint( $atts['columns'] );
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

    ob_start();

    // Reset loop/columns globals when starting a new loop
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = $woocommerce_loop['column'] = '';

    if ( shuffle($rand_product_categories) ) {
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

        foreach ( $rand_product_categories as $category ) {
            wc_get_template( 'content-product_cat.php', array(
                'category' => $category
            ) );
        }

        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    }

    woocommerce_reset_loop();

    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'rand_prod_cat', 'rand_product_categories' );
```

and the loops is ok.thanks in advance

Comment: How many categories do you have in total?

Comment: sorry for late.i have around 30 categories

Comment: And the maximum number of categories you see is 4?

Comment: i have limited the columns to 4 you can see.and sometimes it only shows 1 , sometime 2/3,

Comment: i need to show rand category everytime 4.but randomized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I tested on local WordPress and worked as expected.

`columns` attribute is the visual presentation so it will not affect how many categories are displayed. `number` attribute is the number of categories retrieved. I changed it to 4 and it worked perfectly.

Either way you can optimize your code like this:

```
function rand_product_categories( $atts ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Get shortcode attributes and set default values
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'number'     => 10,
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'columns'    => '4',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'parent'     => 0,
        'ids'        => ''
    ), $atts );

    if ( isset( $atts['ids'] ) ) {
        $ids = explode( ',', $atts['ids'] );
        $ids = array_map( 'trim', $ids );
    } else {
        $ids = array();
    }

    $hide_empty = ( $atts['hide_empty'] == true || $atts['hide_empty'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;

    // get terms and workaround WP bug with parents/pad counts
    $args = array(
        'orderby'    => $atts['orderby'],
        'order'      => $atts['order'],
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        'include'    => $ids,
        'pad_counts' => true,
        'child_of'   => $atts['parent']
    );

    $rand_product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    shuffle( $rand_product_categories );

    // add $atts['number'] here
    $rand_product_categories = array_slice( $rand_product_categories, 0, $atts['number'] );

    // child_of default value is 0, no need to check for parent
    /*if ( '' !== $atts['parent'] ) {
        $rand_product_categories = wp_list_filter( $rand_product_categories, array( 'parent' => $atts['parent'] ) );
    }*/


/*
    // No need to check for hide empty, its already part of the query
    if ( $hide_empty ) {
        foreach ( $rand_product_categories as $key => $category ) {
            if ( $category->count == 0 ) {
                unset( $rand_product_categories[ $key ] );
            }
        }
    }
*/
 /*   if ( $atts['number'] ) {
        $rand_product_categories = array_slice( $rand_product_categories, 0, $atts['number'] );
    }*/

    $columns = absint( $atts['columns'] );
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

    ob_start();

    // Reset loop/columns globals when starting a new loop
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = $woocommerce_loop['column'] = '';

    // Shuffle already done 
   // if ( shuffle($rand_product_categories) ) {
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

        foreach ( $rand_product_categories as $category ) {
            wc_get_template( 'content-product_cat.php', array(
                'category' => $category
            ) );
        }

        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
  //  }

    woocommerce_reset_loop();

    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'rand_prod_cat', 'rand_product_categories' );
```

Comment: thanks.does it shows 4 random categories, everytime refresh?

Comment: i just tested.it works fine.thanks :)